# Interpreting raw memory as a c++ object — without explicitly creating it

Tags: c++, memory, c++20, undefined-behavior, lifetime

In the following code a chunk of raw memory (assume it is a network buffer allocated with malloc) is being interpreted as an object. Note that the HwAddr object is never created explicitly and thus its lifetime does not begin. Accessing non-static members of such object would result in UB as it happens in parsePacket().

There appears to be a loophole, however, in that if HwAddr class could be an implicit-lifetime object the code below would be valid. Unfortunately, this isn't the case because this class isn't an aggregate.

The question: is my argument correct? Would it be sufficient to make the HwAddr class an aggregate (e.g. by removing non-default constructor) for the code to not contain an UB? What else am I missing?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct HwAddr {
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> bytes;

    HwAddr() = default;
    HwAddr(const uint8_t *data)
        : bytes{data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5]} {}

    bool is_multicast() const noexcept {
        return htons(bytes[0]) & (1<<0);
    }

    bool is_local() const noexcept {
        return htons(bytes[0]) & (1<<1);
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<HwAddr>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<HwAddr>);
//static_assert(std::is_aggregate_v<HwAddr>); // oopsie!!!
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<HwAddr,const uint8_t*>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<HwAddr>);

struct Packet {
    HwAddr *mac;
    uint16_t priority;
};

void parsePacket(Packet &pkt, uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len) {
    std::size_t const kHwAddrOffset = 42;
    pkt.mac = reinterpret_cast<HwAddr*>(buf + kHwAddrOffset);
    pkt.priority = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(buf);
    if (pkt.mac->is_local() ) { // UB !!!
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, what would be the best way to "safeguard" such constructs against an UB? Are static checks for is_trivially_constructible/is_aggregate enough?

PS. This appears to be the case of [P0593](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html)...

Comment: "*Unfortunately, this isn't the case because this class isn't an aggregate.*" That's not the definition of an [implicit lifetime type.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Implicit-lifetime_class)

Comment: True, this is only one of the conditions, the other two being to have a trivial constructor and a trivial destructor.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your confusion here. Are you unable to tell if the type is implicit lifetime?

Comment: Two things: 1) at this point I'm not sure if these conditions are sufficient, 2) I want an automated checkю

Comment: Your question is confused then. See, your question starts from the presumption that `HwAddr` is *not* implicit lifetime. But your reasoning for this is incorrect; a class can still be implicit lifetime without being an aggregate. So you first need a *correct* explanation as to why `HwAddr` is not implicit lifetime. And please insert this information into your question.

Comment: If your question really is "I have a type, and I want to do a compile-time check to make sure it is implicit lifetime. What do I do?" then most of the text of your question doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Ok, I somehow misread the definition of an implicit-lifetime class, so this class IS eligible, correct? For the compile check, do you think it is worth a separate question?

Comment: Well, there are no answers yet, so I say just edit it to make it about what you mean for it to be about.

Comment: I am afraid currently such approach is stil UB because such object is technically unititalized and reading uninitialized value is UB. You still need somethiung like [std::start_lifetime_as](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2590r0.pdf) that explicitly states: `The object representation of A is the contents of the storage prior to
the call to start_lifetime_as as if by calling memcpy from a copy of the original storage,
except that the storage is not accessed.`